# Equivalent of JkMount with AJP in Tomcat 6

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

It is my understanding that JkMount is deprecated and no longer used in tomcat6. How would I make the following rule with only ajp?

`JkMount /*/servlet/* ajp13`

Comment: isn't all the content served from the tomcat? Why are you using "/*/"?

Answer (score 1):

`JkMount` is not part of tomcat. It is a configuration directive of the module `mod_jk`, from apache, and it is not deprecated.

You have a couple of options to forward requests from apache to an application running on tomcat. One is the use of `mod_jk`, which basic syntax (this is an Apache directive) is:

```
JkMount [url] [worker]
```

In your example, the worker is named `ajp13` which is an unlucky choice because it is mistaken with the name of the protocol `mod_jk` uses. Workers are configured in `workers.properties` on your reverse proxy (apache2 - and the path depends on wich OS you are using). You can have a deeper look to configuration options of worker.properties at the [tomcat connector reference guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html). Yu can read this [on apache directives related to mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html)

Other option is to use the module mod-proxy-ajp. It is sure simpler to configure but depending on the scenario you might want to use `mod_jk` over `mod-proxy-ajp`. There is a related discussion on this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/182289/mod-proxy-vs-mod-proxy-ajp-vs-mod-jk), and another one on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081918/apache-to-tomcat-mod-jk-vs-mod-proxy).

Personally I believe that nowadays there is no need to recompile practically anything. Debian has its own package for mod_jk, and you can get rpm files for rhel and rh-like distros.